# Visual Studio no carga los proyectos correctamente

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual, control-de-versiones, vs

tengo un proyecto alojado en Azure con el cual hago el control de codigo fuente. Implemente esto para poder trbajar desde mi pc personal y tambien desde una maquina virtual desde mi pc de trabajo. Pero al Instalar Visual Studio en mi maquina virtual y descargar el proyecto me aparecen los siguientes mensajes en cada proyecto que existe en el repositorio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacerle  click derecho aparece una opciones de Instalar dependencias, Volver a cargar el proyecto y Recargar el Proyecto con dependencias, pero todas abren el Visual Studio Instaler, y me dicen que todas las dependencias ya estan instalad y me vuelve a inicial el proyecto al igual que antes.

La maquina virtual tiene Windows Server 2012 R2 aunque creo que este no seria el problema de eso, trabajo con Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Me ha pasado eso cuando bajas clonas un proyecto y los folders o el nombre tiene espacios, al clonarlo la carpeta cambia por ejemplo de "proyecto de visual" a "proyecto%20de%20visual" entonces en el archivo .sln el folder o la ruta del proyecto esta  con espacios, pero en realidad cuando se bajo quedo con  %20

Comment: Ve a la carpeta del proyecto y revisa las rutas en el archivo .sln, abrelo con notepad o algo asi y checa que las rutas donde estan los proyectos exista y que los proyectos tambien existan.